# WooCommerce variable product not work add to card

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a problem with my variable product in WooCommerce.

When I want the add the product in the card I have a problem.
It's always show the error : Please choose the options product ... (or something like that because me it's french language) even if a choose option product correctly.

I found that this in my function.php cause the problem. (is for a link to login / login out)

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );

function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
   if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'secondary') {
       $items .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">Bienvenue ' . $user->display_name . '</a></li>';
       $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) ) .'">Déconnexion</a></li>';
   }
   elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'secondary') {
       $items .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">Connexion</a></li>';
   }
   return $items;
}
```

*I use the latest version of WooCommerce.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

The variable `$items` was conflicting with another variable.
So I change all `$items` to `$itemsMenu` and it's work well now.